# Keep State Of Controls in GridView Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to store and keep state of controls in a Grid View. For example in each row there is an upload button and some other interactive objects and a button which will do some commands for the target row (for example uploading the file which is selected by upload button in that row.)

Think In each row, I select a file with upload controls, now I just upload one of them in a row, By clicking the button for that row for uploading the file, Other rows' upload buttons and controls will reset to their first state after uploading that file in that row, and I need to skip this reaction.

Hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the GridView bind code is within an if statment like this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    BindGridView();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, I think It should not be as easy as it seems.

Comment: Before uploading the file update the database and then rebind the gridview again.